# Strange message when starting Vim while trying to set up Vundle

Tags: vim, vundle

I'm trying to install Vundle in order to have an IDE for Python in Vim. But every time I start Vim it gives me this message:

```
    Name        Args       Address   Complete  Definition
    Bundle      +                                  call vundle#config#bundle(<args>)
!   BundleClean ?                                  PluginClean<bang>
    BundleDocs  0                                  PluginDocs
!   BundleInstall ?                    custom        PluginInstall<bang> <args>
!   BundleList  0                                  PluginList<bang>
!   BundleSearch ?                    custom        PluginSearch<bang> <args>
    BundleUpdate 0                                  PluginInstall!
    Plugin      +                                  call vundle#config#bundle(<args>)
!   PluginClean ?                                  call vundle#installer#clean('!' == '<bang>')
    PluginDocs  0                                  call vundle#installer#helptags(g:vundle#bundles)
!   PluginInstall *                    custom        call vundle#installer#new('!' == '<bang>', <f-args>)
!   PluginList  0                                  call vundle#installer#list('!' == '<bang>')
!   PluginSearch ?                    custom        call vundle#scripts#all('!' == '<bang>', <q-args>)
    PluginUpdate *                    custom        PluginInstall! <args>
!   VundleClean ?                                  PluginClean<bang>
    VundleDocs  0                                  PluginDocs
!   VundleInstall ?                    custom        PluginInstall<bang> <args>
!   VundleSearch ?                    custom        PluginSearch<bang> <args>
    VundleUpdate *                    custom        PluginInstall! <args>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I've used the code found in the [Vundle repository](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim).

Any idea on how to stop this behavior?

Comment: Can you paste the part of your `.vimrc` that deals with Vundle? I think you might be calling it wrong.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane here: https://github.com/GiuseppeMinardi/GiusVimRC/blob/master/VIMRC

Comment: Fixed link to Giuseppe’s `.vimrc`: https://github.com/GiuseppeMinardi/Configs/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [your `.vimrc`](https://github.com/GiuseppeMinardi/GiusVimRC/blob/9c76d8cd3936b2967edc2be642cfb546bb79238c/VIMRC), you forgot to add these lines at the start:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
```

The [Vundle Quick Start](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start) says those lines are required. They must be placed somewhere before the `set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` statement.

Comment: Done, I still have this problem

Comment: @GiuseppeMinardi There is one line where you write `Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'`. That should be `Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` like the others. Does that get rid of the error?

Comment: Nope, I still get the message

Comment: I sill get the error message even if I put the code diectly from the Vundle repo